# Can you customize A4 page html css?

Tags: html, css

I like to know is possible to recreate design this A4 page using only html and css?

[image: A4page]

Comment: You can use the css @media selector for applying CSS to print pages.

Comment: @Celsiuss I think the question author means the round edge effect

Comment: @Programmer I think that he wants the round edge effect with a fixed aspect ratio

Comment: If you mean just the content of the a4 page then yes, but if you mean the effect of the paper at the bottom right corner then... someone can reach close enough but it requires a lot of work.